# LINQ join using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, join, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I am using code from the article below to dynamically build LINQ queries.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq

Although there are better suggestions on the internet, it was serving my purpose until now and Fitim Skenderi's code is easy to understand too.

I now need to build queries at run-time by joining two or more tables. I cannot find any example online.

My Code:

```
public enum Op
{
    IsEqualTo,
    IsGreaterThan,
    IsLessThan,
    IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    IsLessThanOrEqualTo,
    Contains,
    StartsWith,
    EndsWith
}

public class Filter
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Op Operation { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public static class ExpressionBuilder
{
    private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
    private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters, bool matchAll)
    {
        if (filters.Count == 0)
            return null;

        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression exp = null;

        if (filters.Count == 1)
            exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
        else if (filters.Count == 2)
            exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1], matchAll);
        else
        {
            while (filters.Count > 0)
            {
                var f1 = filters[0];
                var f2 = filters[1];

                if (exp == null)
                    exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1], matchAll);
                else
                {
                    if(matchAll)
                    exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1], matchAll));
                    else
                        exp = Expression.OrElse(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1], matchAll));
                }

                filters.Remove(f1);
                filters.Remove(f2);

                if (filters.Count == 1)
                {
                    if(matchAll)
                    exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));
                    else
                        exp = Expression.OrElse(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));

                    filters.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
    }

    private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);   

        UnaryExpression constant = null;
        if (member.Type == typeof(Decimal?))
        {
           constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(Decimal.Parse(filter.Value.ToString())), member.Type);
        }
        else if (member.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
           constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value.ToString())), member.Type);
        }
        else if (member.Type == typeof(int?))
        {
            constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(int.Parse(filter.Value.ToString())), member.Type);
        }
        else
        {
            if (filter.Value.GetType() != member.Type)
            {
                object result = Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, member.Type);
                constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(result), member.Type);
            }
            else 
            {
                constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(filter.Value), member.Type);
            }

        }

        switch (filter.Operation)
        {
            case Op.IsEqualTo:
                return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

            case Op.IsGreaterThan:
                return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

            case Op.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.IsLessThan:
                return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

            case Op.IsLessThanOrEqualTo:
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.Contains:
                return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);

            case Op.StartsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);

            case Op.EndsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T> (ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter filter2, bool matchAll)
    {
        Expression bin1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
        Expression bin2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);

        if(matchAll)
        return Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
        else
            return Expression.OrElse(bin1, bin2);
    }
}
```

The end user selects the fields (of Contract table), conditions (=, >, Contains etc) and enters a value for each selected fields to be queried. Based on the end user's selection List filterCollection is created and the query is generated. The code is below:

```
if (filterCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            var deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Contract>(filterCollection, true).Compile(); //true if all criteria are to be matched
            contractList = ctx.Contracts.Where(deleg).ToList();
            gridControl1.DataSource = contractList;
        }
```

It works fine for single table. But now I need to let the end user select fields, conditions and values of another table called Customer. The Customer table and the Contract table is linked by 'CustomerID'.

How do I build the query if the user wants to find all contracts of a Customer called 'John' (Field: Name, Table: Customer). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the structure of the model you have, If there is navigation properties between `Customer` and `Contract` classes or not, and how you distinguish between two classes properties.

Comment: There is navigation property between two tables. The issue is that I cannot hard code the query. The join needs to be done at run-time. As you can see contractList = ctx.Contracts.Where(deleg).ToList();. I can do the same with the other table. But I have been so far unable to do a join with Expression Tree.

Comment: you need something like this  in your delegate: `x=>x.Prop1>12 && x.Navigation.Prop2<22`? Or you want to invoke `Join` method of the `IQueryable`?

Comment: a bit late to the party, but first you need to create the linq statement manually for few examples, then once you are satisfied that it is, then you can convert it ti an expression.